# How to get sed to work for parametric expansions?

Tags: bash, sed

The current script is

```
for r in $path/[0-9]*.tst; do

sed -i s/val1/${r%.tst}/ $path/foo.bar
sed -i s/val2/${var2}/ $path/foo.bar
sed -i s/val3/${var3}/ $path/foo.bar
sed -i s/val4/${var4}/ $path/foo.bar

cat $path/foo.bar
done
```

Values 2-4 work fine; however, val1 remains unchanged. This is true even when I use ${r} instead of ${r%.tst}.

Are there any glaring errors in this snippet?

Comment: The glaring error I see is that `sed` tries to replace `val2` to `val4` on every iteration instead of just once before or after the loop, this seems pointless from what you posted… I think you should really share your real script in whole.

Comment: Boom, the slash in the beginning of the ${r%.tst} was it. You're good at what you do.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `$r` will look like `path/file.tst` so when it's expanded (whether with or without the dot extension), `sed` will see something like

```
sed s/val1/path/file/
```

which will cause an error because the `/` in the replacement string is interpreted as the terminating `/` of the `sed s/pattern/replacement/`

You can overcome that by choosing any other character as sed's pattern separator - choose something that's not going to be in your filename or path e.g. `@` (although of course that *is* a legal filename character). So

```
"s@val1@${r%.tst}@"
```

(I've used double-quotes here: they will allow variable expansion while preventing other potential gotchas such as glob expansion).

---

As a matter of style (and efficiency) I'd suggest **not** making multiple `sed` calls to edit the same file - you can chain multiple replacement expressions in GNU sed with `-e` e.g.

```
sed -i -e "s@val1@${r%.tst}@" -e "s@val2@${var2}@" -e ...
```

or make use of the `-f scriptfile` option and use a here-document:

```
for r in "$path"/[0-9]*.tst; do

sed -i -f- "$path/foo.bar" << EOF
s@val1@${r%.tst}@
s@val2@${var2}@
s@val3@${var3}@
s@val4@${var4}@
EOF

cat "$path/foo.bar"

done
```